# Update DIV with Ajax Asp.Net MVC C #

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-mvc, morris.js

I'm setting up a Ticket Tracking Panel, basically there are two things, 4 fields and 1 chart. I would like to update them periodically, I've tried:

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="10" />
```

However, this reloads the entire page, performing a refresh. What I need is to reload the fields and chart without this refresh. From what I found on the internet, I can do this with AJAX, but I do not know how, because I'm still starting with the development.

```
@using System.Data
@model DataSet

@{ ViewBag.Title = "Home Page";}


<!-- container-fluid -->
<div class="container-fluid">

    <!-- Page Heading -->
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-12">
            <h2 class="page-header">
                Tickets AGP
            </h2>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- /Page Heading -->


    <!-- Campos -->
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-6">
            <div class="panel panel-danger">
                <div class="panel-heading">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-xs-3">
                            <i class="fa fa-tasks fa-5x"></i>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-xs-9 text-right">

                            <div class="huge">

                                @foreach (DataRow row in Model.Tables[1].Rows)
                                {

                                    if (@row["status"].Equals("Aberto - Aguardando Aprovação"))
                                    {
                                        @row["quantidade_status"]
                                    }
                                }

                            </div>
                            <div>Aguardando Aprovação</div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- /Campos -->


    <!-- Gráficos Morris Charts -->
    <div class="row">

        <div class="col-lg-6">
            <div class="panel panel-primary">
                <div class="panel-heading">
                    <h3 class="panel-title"><i class="fa fa-long-arrow-right"></i> Atendimento AGP</h3>
                </div>
                <div class="panel-body">
                    <div id="morris-bar-agp"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<!-- /container-fluid -->

@section scripts {

    <!-- Script que carrega as informacoes do grafico-->
    <script>

    $(document).ready(function (){

        $.get('@Url.Action("GetData", "Home")', function (data) {
            console.log(data);


            Morris.Bar({

                element: 'morris-bar-agp',
                xkey: 'admAtribuido',
                ykeys: ['quantidade_admAtribuido'],
                labels: ['Tickets Atendidos'],
                barRatio: 0.4,
                xLabelAngle: 10,
                gridTextSize: 12,
                gridTextColor: '#000',
                hideHover: 'auto',
                resize: true,
                data: data
            });

            $(window).trigger('resize');
            $('svg').height(650);

            });
    });

    </script>
}
```

This is the code of Action GetData (), I believe that the query is not important in this case, so I put that generic there, because mine is very big:

```
[HttpGet]
public JsonResult GetData()
{

    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=xxx.xx.xxx.xxx;Initial Catalog=XXX;User ID=xxxxxx;Password=xxxxx"))
    {

     string query = select * from table

     using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query))
     {
            cmd.Connection = con;
            using (SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd))
            {
                sda.Fill(ds);
            }

        }
        var json = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(ds.Tables[2]);

        var obj = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json, (new[] { new { admAtribuido = "", quantidade_admAtribuido = 0 } }).GetType());

        return Json(obj, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
}
```

Here is the Action Index () that sends the field data to be retrieved in View:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();

    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=xxx.xx.xxx.xxx;Initial Catalog=XXX;User ID=xxxxxx;Password=xxxxxx"))
    {
        query select * from table

    using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query))
        {
            cmd.Connection = con;
            using (SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd))
            {

                sda.Fill(ds);
            }
        }
    }

    return View(ds);
}
```

Comment: Have you thought about using multiple partial views so you can update them independently rather than as one whole page

Comment: So I'm starting now with Asp.Net development, how would I do it?

Comment: Not sure how far along you're achieving this, but you might be only missing the `setInterval([wrap you $.get method in there], 1000);` function that will call it every second

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with AJAX like this:

```
@section scripts {

<!-- Script que carrega as informacoes do grafico-->
<script>

$(document).ready(function (){
    setTimeout(function() {
     $.get('@Url.Action("GetData", "Home")', function (data) {
        console.log(data);


        Morris.Bar({

            element: 'morris-bar-agp',
            xkey: 'admAtribuido',
            ykeys: ['quantidade_admAtribuido'],
            labels: ['Tickets Atendidos'],
            barRatio: 0.4,
            xLabelAngle: 10,
            gridTextSize: 12,
            gridTextColor: '#000',
            hideHover: 'auto',
            resize: true,
            data: data
        });

        $(window).trigger('resize');
        $('svg').height(650);

        });
    }, 1000); //(1 sec) last parameter is in milliseconds.

});

</script>
}
```

More information on [setTimeout](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_settimeout.asp).

Comment: It seems to me to be an alternative, however how can I check if it works, so I understood, according to my code every time I upgrade, console.log will run right?

Comment: Yes, the `console.log` should print the data if the HTTP call is successful.